# How to extract document stream from xml in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, xml-parsing

I am getting an XML as a response from web service. One of the tags in this xml actually contains the content of a document which the web service is sending as a stream. If I try to extract the document after parsing as NSString and then converting it to NSData to load into a webView, UIwebView is not able to display the document and throws an error:

```
EXCEPTION CPMessageException: (null)
```

Below is the sample of the xml which i am getting as a response (I can't provide the exact xml, as it's confidential):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><content xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns6:BinaryContent" pageModifier="" pageNumber="0" format="msw8"><ns6:renditionType>PRIMARY</ns6:renditionType><ns6:Value>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</ns6:Value></content></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

I need to extract `<ns6:Value>`, which is actually contents of a document, and display it in UIwebView. 
I need some guidance on this.

Comment: Finally found the solution. Basically the stream was coming as base64 encoded format. So first i need to decode which will provide me the correct NSData. Use any base 64 encoding/decoding library -- Closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Basically the stream was coming as base64 encoded format. So first i need to decode which will provide me the correct NSData. Use any base 64 encoding/decoding library.